# Linq to group by 2 columns in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a simple Linq query, which groups by one field `Team`:

```
var qbt = db.Calls.GroupBy(x => x.team).Select(call => new
        {
            Team = call.Key,
            Number=call.Count()
        });
```

Which returns:

```
Team  Number
ta    100 
tb    98 
tc    123
```

How do I change the query to have an additional column "status", so that it returns:

```
Team  Number Status
ta    40     Open
ta    60     Closed
tb    58     Open
tb    40     Closed
tc    1      Open
tc    122    Closed
```

I tried adding another group:

```
var qbt = db.Calls.GroupBy(x => x.team).GroupBy(y => y.status).Select(call => new
        {
            Team = call.Key,
            Status = call.Key2,
            Number=call.Count()
        });
```

... but that won't compile.

Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create new anonymous type inside groupping, that should do the trick.

```
var qbt = db.Calls
    .GroupBy(x => new { Team = x.team, Status = x.status })
    .Select(call => new
    {
        Team = call.Key.Team,
        Status = call.Key.Status,
        Number=call.Count()
    });
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. That should be `Team = call.Key.Team` and `Status = call.Key.Status` (`Key2` wont exist, and `Key` will be the anonymous type created in the groupby)

Comment: Right - didn't even noticed that part, as it was copy-pasted from question; though the most important part seems to be all right. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can group on an anonymous type:

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.team, x.status })
```

With the corresponding select:

```
.Select(call => new
    {
        Team = call.Key.team,
        Status = call.Key.status,
        Number = call.Count()
    });
```