# Transform a table to add more columns in Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I received very helpful advise in a previous post: [Linq to group by 2 columns in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791173/linq-to-group-by-2-columns-in-c-sharp) - I'm trying to expand on that now, so that my ViewModel looks the way it should for the view:

My first query:

```
var qbt = db.Calls.GroupBy(calls => new { calls.assignedteam, calls.status })
            .Select(call => new StatusByTeamViewModel1
        {
            Team = call.Key.assignedteam,
            Status = call.Key.status,
            Number = call.Count()
        }).OrderBy(z => z.Team).ThenBy(z => z.Status);
```

Returns:

```
Team  Number Status
ta    40     Open
ta    60     Closed
tb    58     Open
tb    40     Closed
tc    1      Open
tc    122    Closed
```

I want to take that table, and transform it to:

```
Team Open Closed
ta   40   60
tb   58   40
tc   1    122
```

I was trying the query below, but am getting myself mixed up - all of the Teams show just 1 or 0 in each if the Open/Closed columns:

```
        var qbt2 = qbt.GroupBy(x => x.Team)
          .Select(call => new StatusByTeamAllViewModel2
          {
              Team = call.Key,
              Open = qbt2.Where(it => it.Status == "Open" && it.Team==call.Key).Count(),
              Closed = qbt2.Where(it => it.Status == "Closed" && it.Team == call.Key).Count(),

          });
```

I am also trying in LinqPad, but having difficulty getting it to work inthere too.

Thanks for your help,

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here won't even compile, because you're defining `qbt2` on the left-hand side, and using it on the right-hand side. Now, assuming that you meant `qbt` on the right-hand side, that's a rather inefficient implementation to `GroupBy`, and then walk the whole sequence looking for matching keys.  The `GroupBy` already gives you the sequence elements that you need, so use it. And then, barring both of those mistakes, you're counting the number of rows that match a given `Team, Status` pair, rather than summing the `Number` value for a given pair. Thus:

```
var qbt2 = 
    qbt.GroupBy(x => x.Team)
       .Select(g => new StatusByTeamAllViewModel2 {
           Team = g.Key,
           Open = g.Where(x => x.Status == "Open").Sum(x => x.Number)
           Closed = g.Where(x => x.Status == "Closed").Sum(x => x.Number)
       });
```